# knockout bindingHandler doesn't work: Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, binding, fadeout

I`m creating a binding with knockout...see the code

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    // Start visible/invisible according to initial value

    var shouldDisplay = valueAccessor();
    $(element).toggle(shouldDisplay);

    // Handle mouse events on the stars
  },

  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    // On update, fade in/out
    var shouldDisplay = valueAccessor();

    shouldDisplay ? $(element).fadeIn() : $(element).fadeOut();

  } 
};
```

...
something seems to be wrong with the `fadeOut()` function on the last line:
the Editor alerts:

> "expected an assignment or function call and instead saw expression"

I´ve no idea why, since `fadeOut()` is obviously a function...

Comment: Can you share the HTML where you apply this binding handler?

Comment: sure.... <h3 data-bind="fadeVisible: pointsUsed() > pointsBudget">You've used too many points! </h3>

Comment: This is essentially here: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
ko.unwrap(shouldDisplay)
```

on each of your shouldDisplay variables.

Comment: yeah but the tag  will only display... I want him to fade in and out

Comment: Perhaps output your pointsUsed() and pointsBudget to verify that the returned value of pointsUsed() does not already surpass pointsBudget on load.

Answer (score 0):

The message is from JSLint/JSHist and you can ignore it.

See http://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call